# How Application Wizards behave in Robo framework and VNC Environmnet

Tags: wizard, vnc

I have a application which have multiple Wizards, When try to open in Robo Framework / VNC Environment getting interpret error. But out side of this ENVs its working as expected.

Using both Solaris and Linux servers. Same user and same conditions.
But the error is coming.

Few experts are telling it is Robo/VNC related issue, so that the Wizards are not working as expected in this ENVS.

As this is official work related query, i am not authorized to provide more customer related issues, though can give technical details.

Please help on this issue.

Comment: We need at least the error message to help you...

Comment: Sure, will update the error details in a while:)

Comment: Hi, Please let me know how to attach the error screenshot here

Comment: Error Number :11815 Error Name:"Interpreter error" interpreter error close pipe.This is the main content of the error.

Comment: Please anyone can provide some update on this.I am not able to attach the error screenshot here. Else it could have been more understandable

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498